# Finding and using a syscall

Tags: linux, macos, system-calls, dtruss

I am developing an app on linux and OSX and I need to view the neighbor cache (ipv6) and add ips. I can do this by simply using the "ndp -an" and "ifconfig..." command for example, but it seems rather un-elegant.

I tried to use "dtruss" to analyze which system calls are made but I don't really know where to go from information such as "__sysctl(0x7FFF53BA62D0, 0x6, 0x0)".

Any hints on where to look and how I should proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried `strace` to trace syscalls ? It gives nicer output.

Comment: You could also look at the source code for those commands. For example, https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-307.0.1/ifconfig.tproj/.